# Wordpress. Code to make social media disappear

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I am a student new to Wordpress and CSS and HTML coding in general. I have provided a link of my website below.

https://homepages.shu.ac.uk/~b7009049/wordpress/

What I need help in is making the social media icons that are on the left side of the website disappear upon pressing the + sign that is on top of it. One thing to mention is that I used a plugin called 'layerslider.' and I will type the code on the sheet they provide. As that's where I got the social media icons from.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

add `z-index: 99999999 !important;` to `.fusion-sliding-bar-position-left`

add this `CSS` your `custom css` file

```
.fusion-sliding-bar-position-left {
    z-index: 99999999 !important;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the code isn't working. I typed it word for word

Comment: add this CSS your custom CSS file